# Laravel use custom USER-Model in package

Tags: php, laravel, model, package, laravel-5.5

I´ve developed a package stored in `LaravelRoot/packages/myname/project/` in Laravel.

Inside my package i´ll have to use an extended user-model containing a relationship not mentioned in the default usermodel.

Now here is my question:
How can i override the default User-Model inside my package?

---

More details:

If i receive the current user via `Auth::user()` inside my package i´ll receive an object using the default `App\User`.

I have extended this model containing now a new relationfunction, stored in `LaravelRoot/packages/myname/project/src/App/Models/User` (namespace: `Myname\Myproject\App\Models`).
Here´s my relation-function:

```
/**
 * The roles that belong to the user.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

This relation is only used in my package, so i don´t want to store this function inside the default `App\User`. Is it possible to receive an object of my extended usermodel using `Auth::user()` in my package or do i have to receive this manually each time i need this one?

Comment: Why don't you wish to have a method in your class? One method is better, than two models.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan because i´ll use this package in many other projects. Adding this package to a new project now only contains two steps: 1. Adding the package in the directory structure. 2. Add my package-service-provider. Adding this function to the default user-model would suffer in adding this function each time, i want to use my package.

Comment: Or create a trait and call it in your User Model ! and add it as requirement to your package !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think, the easiest way is to make your package model via extending of `App\User` model. You need just to open `config/auth.php` and to setup your model class.

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => Project\Models\User::class,
    ],
```

You will get correct model via `Auth::user()`.

Comment: Thanks, that´s the correct hint! Now i have added `config(['auth.providers.users.model' => Myname\Myproject\App\Models\User::class]);` to the boot-method inside my package-service-provider.

Comment: @NeronNF, Thanks man it really helped me struggling from an hour